# Findbugs + JSR305: Possibility to specify default behavior?

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs, jsr305

*Note: those annotations, I'm talking about, are specified by JSR305.*

I have the latest Findbugs (1.3.9) and it finds errors **correctly**
when some field, annotated with @Nonnull, is assigned to null.

But, in my project, the "non-null logic" is the **default** case. I would say that
**null is explicitely allowed only in 5% of cases**.

So, it would be very inconvenient
to annotate 95% of fields with @Nonnull. I would rather prefer to annotate those
5% of fields with @Nullable.

*I tried to annotate a whole package with @Nonnull, it doesn't change anything.*

**So, it is somehow possible to specify the default logic?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Fiundbug can deal with the following annotation, but if you want to annotate a all package with "NonNull", you may want to use:

[`@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`](https://github.com/amaembo/jsr-305/blob/d7734b13c61492982784560ed5b4f4bd6cf9bb2c/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.java)

```
/**
 * This annotation can be applied to a package, class or method to indicate that
 * the method parameters in that element are nonnull by default unless there is:
 * <ul>
 * <li>An explicit nullness annotation
 * <li>The method overrides a method in a superclass (in which case the
 * annotation of the corresponding parameter in the superclass applies)
 * <li> there is a default parameter annotation applied to a more tightly nested
 * element.
 * </ul>
 * 
 */
@Documented
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ParametersAreNonnullByDefault {
}
```

See also [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20090310113439/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/11/jsr-305-annotations.html).

Note: at least that annotation is present in [some FindBugs test cases](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/blob/451c28097c22ef8e6f8943e5ebe6a16ff41beff7/findbugsTestCases/src/java/myCollections/package-info.java).

Comment: Thank you, tried it, Findbugs ignores it (on types AND on packages). Must be a bug in Findbugs ;) JSR305 is inactive anyway. Perhaps I should look around for other solutions.

Comment: Article link is dead

Comment: @RikSchaaf Thank you for the feedback. 13 years later, this is not too surprising. I have edited the answer and restored all links.

Answer (score 0):

FindBugs now has [@ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/ReturnValuesAreNonnullByDefault.html). It also has @DefaultAnnotation, @DefaultAnnotationForFields, @DefaultAnnotationForMethods and @DefaultAnnotationForParameters.

But I should disclaim that I haven't used any of those in my projects..